# How do you add a range to the X-Axis in a chart in google sheets via Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm fairly new to Apps Script but familiar with javascript. I've taken a look at the reference guide that's given for sheets but I might be missing it or not sure what I'm looking for. If you insert a regular line chart manually, you have an option to add a range for the X-Axis from selected cells. How would you do this via script? I have this set up so far

```
function BuildOChart(x){
  var chart = sheet.newChart().asLineChart()
  chart.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  chart.addRange(sheet.getRange(x))
  chart.setCurveStyle(Charts.CurveStyle.SMOOTH)
  chart.setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
  chart.setOption("X-Axis", "H1:H100") //Doesn't work
  sheet.insertChart(chart.build())
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by X-Axis? Your question is not clear. Do you mean for a specific data series, you want to associate a given range as the source of values for the x-component of its plotted points? Or do you mean you want to label the X-Axis based on the contents of a given range?

Comment: I think it is labeling the X-Axis based on the contents of a given range. That's the thing, not sure what to call it. When looking at the manual chart editor, it simply gives an option "X-Axis" and then gives you the option to select a range. Pretty sure it would be just labeling the X-Axis from the contents of a range of cells

Comment: Look at the GViz Charts documentation for options

Comment: Alright, but I'm not sure how to plug that in to plain Apps Scripts nor what I'm even looking for

Comment: @tehhowch Alright, got it! I was looking for `useFirstColumnAsDomain` Just was a little confused on how the GViz was treating it with HTML and how the Apps Script documentation was formated

Comment: Feel free to help out future askers by writing a good answer on how you solved it :)